# Procedure works but when turned into a Public Sub to be called it then fails

Tags: vb.net, excel

I wrote the following sub:

```
    Public Sub filterEmployeeSheets(Sheets As Excel.Worksheet, SearchRange As String, Indicator As String, FilterString As String)

    'This Sub is used to filter sheets by deleting any rows
    'that do not contain the value stated in variable filterString

    '@Parameter Sheets to declare sheet(s) name
    '@Parameter SearchRange to set the column to filter
    '@Parameter Indicator determines the =, <> setting
    '@Parameter FilterString to set the string to keep

    Dim lngLr As Long

    With Sheets

        lngLr = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows).Row

        If lngLr > 1 Then
            With .Range(SearchRange & lngLr)
                **.AutoFilter(Field:=1, Criteria1:=Indicator & FilterString)** 'Error is here
                .EntireRow.Delete()
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Public Function ClientSheets(Index As Long) As Excel.Worksheet

    'This function indexes all of the Employee sheets
    'to use in various loops during he instal process
    '@param EmployeeSheets, are the sheets to index

    Select Case Index

        Case 1 : Return xlWSAllEEAnnul
        Case 2 : Return xlWSAllEEHourly
    End Select

    Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index")

End Function
```

When I call it on the procedure below:

```
        Dim xlRefSheets As Excel.Worksheet

        For i As Long = 1 To 2 Step 1

            Dim strOperatorSymbol As String = "<>"

            xlRefSheets = ClientSheets(i)

            filterEmployeeSheets(xlRefSheets, "K5:K", "<>", "Y")

        Next

End Sub
```

I get this error: The command could not be completed by using the range specified. Select a single cell within the range and try the command again. However, If I use the Public Sub as a procedure without the For Loop on a single sheet instead of calling it, it works just fine.

Comment: Wouldn't you need `Sheets(Sheets)` in your with statement, as the way you define it at least? Also using "Sheets" as a variable could get tricky.

Comment: @JoeLaviano You are correct, it could get tricky, I had not realized that. I changed the variable but still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact of calling this function from a loop or from any other part does not have any effect on its performance. What happens in the loop is that the input conditions change and the error is triggered because the referred part cannot deal with any situation.

The error is provoked, most likely, because "Field 1" (i.e., second row of the range `SearchRange & lngLr`) is empty. Thus a correction for your error (bear in mind that `Rows` start from 1 and `Field` from 0):

```
If (.Rows.Count > 1 AndAlso .Rows(2).Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso .Rows(2).Value.ToString().Trim().Length > 0) Then
    .AutoFilter(Field:=1, Criteria1:=Indicator & FilterString)
End If
```

There is another part:

```
 lngLr = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows).Row
```

prone to trigger errors. If no match is found, the range would be `Nothing` and thus `.Row` will trigger an error. It is always safer to do something like:

```
Dim lngLr As Long = 0
Dim findRange As Excel.Range = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows)
If (findRange IsNot Nothing) Then
    lngLr = findRange.Row
End If
```